# C# Windows Form Label BackgroundImage

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I want to set a background image on a `Label`.
I found that [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.backgroundimage%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not allow to do this. However, I want to implement by self.
The code is in below, the problem is that how can I set the background image programmically?
There is still no `BackgroundImage` property to set.

```
class BackgroundImageLabel : Label
{
    public BackgroundImageLabel()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //is BackGroundImage null
        if (this.BackgroundImage != null)
        {

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height),
                this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Width, this.Height,
                   System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);      
        }

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, drawBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
        //base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

### Edit

I got another problem is that the Label is all black whatever I change the settings.
I don't know what the reason is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use *Image* property instead of *BackgroundImage*. What is the problem?

Comment: oh, I don't know that it has the capability of background. Now I know to use the `Image` property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BackgroundImage property is implemented by the Control class, the base class of Label.  So every control has the ability to have a background image.  But as you can tell from the way Label behaves in the designer, they tinkered with it to make it unavailable.

You'll want to find out exactly what they did with it.  You can do so with a decompiler, but today it is best to use the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).  A very slick web site that allows you to easily browse the source code in the .NET Framework.  Type "Label.BackgroundImage" in the search box.

You'll see that nothing particularly drastic happened to it, it just acquired several attributes to *hide* the property.  So first thing you want to do is override BackgroundImage yourself and cancel those attributes again:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class BackgroundImageLabel : Label {
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
     DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public override Image BackgroundImage {
        get {
            return base.BackgroundImage;
        }
        set {
            base.BackgroundImage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Bingo, works fine.

You'll have to set the AutoSize property to False, the probable reason they decided to hide the property.  You can override that too, if you want to, you now know how to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Label already has the [BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.label.backgroundimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. But it is described as "not intended to be used directly from your code". So you may have to provide your own property with another name.

I suppose the problem is that `OnPaint` is never called. To make this work add

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint);
```

to your constructor.